# Iron router meteor to publish only one item in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How do I write my publish method so that iron router gets to subscribe to only on item in my collection

```
Meteor.publish('patients', function(){
return Newpatient.find();  });
```

I have tried a subscription on the routes to one item but it still subscribes to all the items in the collection so I figured it had something to do with the publish method. Please help

Comment: Which item do you want? One with a specific `_id`, the last one in some order, ...?

Comment: yes, one with an _id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a publisher which takes an id as a parameter:

```
Meteor.publish('patient', function (patientId) {
  check(patientId, String);
  return Newpatient.find(patientId);
});
```

Then on the client, you can subscribe like this:

```
Meteor.subscribe('patient', this.params._id);
```

Also see the [subscriptions section](https://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#subscriptions) of the IR guide for more details.